# Restricting available memory for testing on linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, out-of-memory, ram

The machine on which I develop has more memory than the one on which the code will eventually run. I dont have access tothe machine on which it will actually run. This is a 64 bit application and I intend to use the address space but cap physical allocation. I dont want to lock down virtual memory, only physical memory. Is there a way to set limits on a linux machine such that it mimics a system with low RAM. I think `ulimit` does not differentiate between reserved address space vs actual allocation. If there is a way to do it without rebooting with different kernel parameters or, pulling out extra RAM that would be great. May be some /proc tricks.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process and https://github.com/pshved/timeout

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thats perfect. Could add it as answer please so that I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process which suggests using "timeout" from here: https://github.com/pshved/timeout .

Answer (score 1):

If You can change boot command line of the kernel and want to restrict available memory use

```
mem=
```

boot parameter.

For more information check:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Comment: Yeah upvoted, but I want to avoid this because this dev machine is used by more than one person. Cant afford to reboot.